# problen ALSA "ring pointers from a software configuration container"

Tags: linux, alsa

when i use this function and i print val i found 
4611686018427387904=2^(62),
what is this number? i google this number i saw whit response of debug function

i read any web pages and i do not found information about software parameters. 
can you recommend some reading for learn about software parameters?

info function 
snd_pcm_sw_params_get_boundary (const snd_pcm_sw_params_t *params, snd_pcm_uframes_t *val)

"Get boundary for ring pointers from a software configuration container. 
val Returned boundary in frames"

Answer (score 0):

The boundary value can be used with certain functions (when setting the stop threshold or the silence size) to get a special behaviour (disable underruns; fill any samples just played with zeros). Otherwise, its actual value is not interesting.

Comment: but this value have any representation ?

Comment: It is a large integer multiple of the buffer size, but why do you care?

Comment: curiosity, what it is representation? it is a big number, i change the size buffer (increase and decrease), and this number no change, only change when change a string name "hw:0,0" for plughw:0,0 is other number